# Basic concept: how to define a linked list in python?

Tags: python-3.x, linked-list

I know the definition of linked list...each unit have data and point to the next...but how did it implement in python? I am really confused about that...

For example, compare with list in python,
if I want to create a list:

```
l1 = [1, 2, 3]
```

if I want to add element to this list, just use `append()` or `insert()` it is very easy

However, many material said it is need to create a class if you want make a linked list like:

```
class ListNode:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        return

    def has_value(self, value):
        if self.data == value:
            return True
        else:
            return False
node1 = ListNode(2)
node2 = ListNode(1.2)
node3 = ListNode('a')
```

I was wondering if there is some way can make it easier like:

```
(1.2) = (2).next
 ('a') = (1.2).next
```

Besides, I find some methods likne `.val .next .head`, when can it be used?

Comment: `ListNode` representa a *node* in a list, not the list itself. There should be a `List` class that contains a reference to a head node, and defines methods for manipulating the list by following references from the head.

Comment: E.g., `l = List();  l.append(1); l.append(1.2); l.append('a')`. `l.head.data` could refer to `2`, `l.head.next.data` to `1.2`, and `l.head.next.next.data` to `'a'`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing Python lists with linked lists. They are not the same. The one you mention first is a Python list. And the one you mention with a Class, is a Linked List.

---

**LISTS** :

- Python lists are just dynamic arrays.
- Elements of an array are stored at contiguous locations.
- Lists are dynamic arrays that means their size is not fixed, it is
  variable, it can be expanded or shrunk as required.
- Time Complexities : Insertion : O(n), Deletion  : O(n), Accessing an
  element : O(1)

**LINKED LISTS :**

- Whereas a linked list is an altogether different data structure where
  the elements are not stored at contiguous locations, rather linked to
  each other.
- Here each element has a link to next element in the list. For the
  last element of the list, it points to NULL.
- Time Complexities : Insertion : O(1), Deletion  : O(1), Accessing an
  element : O(n)

---

Refer [this](https://realpython.com/linked-lists-python/) for more information on linked lists.

Feel free to comment if you have any queries.